# Unable to set different video duration for capture and edit video in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I am working on project where in i need to set 1 minute for video recording but user should and edit and select the video of 30 second duration.

Below is the code i used to enable 30 second maximum editing time.

```
-(BOOL)startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                                   usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                                   UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate
{

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) || (delegate == nil) || (controller == nil))
    {
        return NO;
    }

    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose movie capture
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    cameraUI.videoMaximumDuration = 30;
    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has provided sample for video editing. you can refer that it is  AVEditDemo sample is in the WWDC 2010 sample code pack I think so....

Comment: But it does not provide two different duration for recording and editing. It has only single function `videoMaximumDuration`

Comment: well then make it custom, record with AVCaptureDevice, AVCaptureDeviceInput, AVCaptureStillImageOutput and then have a custom trim window, or record with native with max time and then have a custom trim

Answer (score 0):

`videoMaximumDuration` can only limit the recording time of the `UIImagePickerController`.

One solution might be to roll your own camera controls— i.e by setting the showsCameraControls property to NO and providing your own controls in a custom view with the cameraOverlayView property—and have your “capture” button call the image picker controller’s -startVideoCapture and -stopVideoCapture regulated by an `NSTimer`

Comment: `videoMaximumDuration` is for both recording and editing video with `cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;` but i need it separate for both i.e. Recoding time should be max 1 minute but editing should be of 30 seconds max

Answer (score 0):

for selecting a video and having the trim function enable to a maximum length of 30 sec you can try this code:

```
-(IBAction)tapSelectVideo:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [imagePicker setVideoMaximumDuration:30];
        [imagePicker setVideoQuality:UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium];

        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats is working fine with me i need 2 different options one for croping and another for capturing video i am able to set only one.